# How to fetch data from firebase and create a class object from it

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, future, snapshot

I am trying to fetch User ratings from firebase and create a class from the data.

this is the class that I need to create when the data arrives::

```
@immutable
class UserRating {
  final String documentId;
  final String ratingJobId;
  final String ratingUserIdGivingRating;
  final String ratingUserIdGettingRating;
  final int? ratingUser;
  final String? ratingComment;
  const UserRating(
      {required this.documentId,
      required this.ratingJobId,
      required this.ratingUserIdGivingRating,
      required this.ratingUserIdGettingRating,
      this.ratingUser,
      this.ratingComment});

  // acts as constructor
  UserRating.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
      : documentId = snapshot.id,
        ratingJobId = snapshot.data()[ratingJobIdColumn],
        ratingUserIdGivingRating =
            snapshot.data()[ratingUserIdGivingRatingColumn],
        ratingUserIdGettingRating =
            snapshot.data()[ratingUserIdGettingRatingColumn],
        ratingUser = snapshot.data()[ratingUserColumn],
        ratingComment = snapshot.data()[ratingCommentColumn];
}
```

here is the code to make the request from firebase ( this is where the issue is because I am having a hard time dealing with the snapshot )

Another issue that I am having is that the data might not exist yet, so if there is no userRating, I need to return something.... not sure how to deal with that either. any help would be amazing!

```
  final userRating = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user rating');

 Future getUserRatingPerJob({
    required String ratingJobId,
    required String ratingUserIdGivingRating,
  }) async {
    await userRating
        .where(
          ratingJobIdColumn,
          isEqualTo: ratingJobId,
        )
        .where(
          ratingUserIdGivingRatingColumn,
          isEqualTo: ratingUserIdGivingRating,
        ); // this is where I need to do something to return UserRating object
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I got to work.

is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
  Future getUserRatingPerJob({
    required String ratingJobId,
    required String ratingUserIdGivingRating,
  }) async {
    var _userRating;

    await userRating
        .where(
          ratingJobIdColumn,
          isEqualTo: ratingJobId,
        )
        .where(
          ratingUserIdGivingRatingColumn,
          isEqualTo: ratingUserIdGivingRating,
        )
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        _userRating = CloudUserRating(
          documentId: element.id,
          ratingJobId: element[ratingJobIdColumn],
          ratingUserIdGettingRating: element[ratingUserIdGettingRatingColumn],
          ratingUserIdGivingRating: element[ratingUserIdGivingRatingColumn],
          ratingUser: element[ratingUserColumn],
          ratingComment: element[ratingCommentColumn],
        );
      });
    });
    return _userRating;
  }
```